# Direct URL to Evernote notebook, note and tag

Tags: api, url, evernote

Our product (Yoke.io) integrates Evernote through REST API. We need to generate direct URL link to a specific notebook, note or tag so that user can click the link to access them.

However, current URL format contains parameters named "ses", "sh" and "sds" in addition to the ids for notebook/note/tag. I have no idea what these parameters mean and if they are different for different users, platforms, etc.

For example, if I want to access a notebook with id "3ec5f3c1-bd4d-4f94-b924-367b13eaf3bc", and generate the following links:

1. https://www.evernote.com/Home.action#b=3ec5f3c1-bd4d-4f94-b924-367b13eaf3bc
2. https://www.evernote.com/Home.action#b=3ec5f3c1-bd4d-4f94-b924-367b13eaf3bc&ses=4&sh=1&sds=5&

The first link (#1) won't work but the second link (#2) works.

I could hard-code "ses", "sh" and "sds" parameters in the URL but my feelings is that these parameters will change for different users.

Could anyone explain more on what are these parameters for and how I can generate a direct URL link to a specific Evernote notebook/note/tag?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Regards,

Tao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ses`, `sh` and `sds` are hash parameters we use when serializing the state of the web client. If you try manipulating the hash parameters to get the web client into a certain state, note that these are undocumented APIs and are subject to change at any time. That said, they won't change super often.

None of those three parameters will change on a per-user basis, they represent the "view" of the client you're in at the time. The simplest way to get a url in the format you like is to navigate to that view in the web client, copy the hash, and replace note and/or notebook guids in the url (`b` for the notebook guid and `n` for the note guid).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Unfortunately the links in our product is generated automatically without any manual process involved. Could we assume that these parameters are the same for all web client (such as all browsers) and only different for mobile client such as IOS or Android? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, same links for all browsers, although we don't support the web client on iOS or Android, so it won't work there. It'll work on any browser on desktop.